# Error in showing stargazer output in Jupyter notebook using IRdisplayl::display_html

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, stargazer

```
m <- capture.output(stargazer(lm_enroll,lm_grades,lm_score, 
          digits = 3,
          header = FALSE,
          type = "html", 
          se = rob_se,
          title = "Linear Panel Regression Model",
          model.numbers = FALSE)

#stargazer () function will automatically output, the output text captured by capture.output ()
IRdisplay::display_html(paste("<center>","",m,"","</center>"))
```

This results in no image both using opera and Chrome. I am using a jupyter notebook in R with conda. Any workaround to make this work? The lm_* are linear regression models and stargazer produces a correct html output, the error then occurs in the final line.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(IRdisplay) #the package that you need
display_html(toString(m))
```